# Don't want email to send if "Null" Value in cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

My script is currently set to not send email if the emailSentCol !== Email_Sent.  I also would like it to not send if the cell in the emailSentCol is empty.  Any suggestions?  Thank you all.  Line 12

```
function myFunction() {
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Administrators");
  if (sheet != null) {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var startRow = 1; //The starting row of data (zero indexed)
    var emailCol = 1; //The column that the email address is in (zero indexed)
    var messageCol = 28; //The column that the message is in (zero indexed)
    var emailSentCol = 29; //The column that the EMAIL_SENT note is in (zero indexed)
    for (var i = startRow; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][emailSentCol] !== EMAIL_SENT) {
        var emailAddress = data[i][emailCol];
        var subject = "Tuition Reimbursement Status";
        var message = data[i][messageCol];
        if(emailAddress !== null && emailAddress !== '' && emailAddress !== "") {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          sheet.getRange(i+1,emailSentCol+1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your if construct to be as follows:

```
if (data[i][emailSentCol] && data[i][emailSentCol] !== EMAIL_SENT) {
```

This ensures that data[i][emailSentCol] must be defined and non-null prior to your check to see if it's not sent.